# How to create tree like structure

Tags: c#, data-structures

I want to create the data structure like below.
[image]

For this one I want go for keyvaluepair structure. But I am unable to create it.

```
public class NewStructure
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>> exportDict;
}
```

Is it a right way. If so how I can insert values to it. If I insert like

```
NewStructure ns = new NewStructure();
ns.exportDict.Add("mainvar",Dictionary<"subvar",true>);
```

it is giving compile error. 
Nothing comes to my mind. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of error by

```
Dictionary<string, bool> values = new Dictionary<string, bool> ();
values.Add("subvar", true);
ns.exportDict.Add("mainvar", values);
```

But probably you`d better try something like this:

```
class MyLeaf
{
  public string LeafName {get; set;}
  public bool LeafValue {get; set;}
}
class MyTree
{
  public string TreeName {get; set;}
  public List<MyLeaf> Leafs = new List<MyLeaf>();
}
```

And then

```
MyTree myTree = new MyTree();
myTree.TreeName = "mainvar";
myTree.Leafs.Add(new MyLeaf() {LeafName = "subvar", LeafValue = true});
```

Comment: He also has to initialize the `exportDict` Dictionary

Comment: @Jleru.. I want to create more than 2 such type of objects and want to retrieve them. Is your example is suitable for that one?

Comment: Of course! You can create List of MyTrees and populate them as you want

Answer (score 1):

For one, you'll have to initialize each of the dictionaries before you add to them:

```
exportDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
Dictionary<string,bool> interiorDict = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
interiorDict.Add("subvar", true);
exportDict.Add("mainvar", interiorDict);
```

But if you know your interior dictionary is only going to have one key value pair then you can do:

```
exportDict = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string,bool>>();
exportDict.Add("mainvar", new KeyValuePair<string,bool>("subvar", true));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on `C# 4.0`, you can accomplish this with a `Dictionary<>` of `KeyValuePair<>`

Your `NewStructure` would become

```
public class NewStructure
{
    public Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, bool>> exportDict =
        new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, bool>>(); //this is still a dictionary!
}
```

and you'd use it like this:

```
NewStructure ns = new NewStructure();
ns.exportDict.Add("mainvar",new KeyValuePair<string,bool>("subvar",true));
```

With a dictionary of dictionaries you would make each "leaf" a list in itself.

Comment: shall we made that Dictionary object exportDict to `KeyValuePair` type?

Comment: no, exportDict would still be a Dictionary. I added its initialization for completeness.